# Render Multiple Pandas Dataframe Styles to one HTML email body

Tags: python, css, pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

I have code that sends an email using an html text. It has only been used so far to send one formatted dataframe at a time. I would like to combine the different style objects into one html body to send out. For example, if I had `df_style1` and `df_style2`, how can I use the send_mail function to send both tables?

```
   styles = [dict(selector = "th", props = [("text-align", "center")])]
   df_style = (
      df.style
      .set_properties(**{"width": "7em"})
      .set_table_attributes('table border="1" class="pure-table"')
      .set_table_styles(styles)
      .set_caption(caption)
   )
   def send_report(df_style, report_date, table_title):
      send_mail(
          username = "test@test.com",
          password = 'abcde',
          from_='test@test.com',
          to = 'test@test.com',
          subject = "Test",
          html_text = df_style.render(),        
       )
    def send_mail(
        username=None,
        password=None,
        from_=None,
        to=None,
        subject=None,
        html_text=None,
        attachment=None,
        smtp_server="smtp.office365.com",
    ):
        smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, 587)
        smtpObj.ehlo()
        logger.info(smtpObj.ehlo_msg)
        smtpObj.starttls()
        smtpObj.login(username, password)
   
        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        msg["Subject"] = subject
        msg["From"] = from_
        if isinstance(to, str):
            msg["To"] = to
        elif isinstance(to, list):
            msg["To"] = ", ".join(to)
        else:
            raise TypeError('"to" must be either a string or a list')
    
        # Create the body of the message (a plain-text and an HTML version).
    
        if html_text is not None:
            html = html_text
            part2 = MIMEText(html, "html")
            msg.attach(part2)
    
        if attachment is not None:
            with open(attachment, "rb") as f:
                part = MIMEApplication(f.read(), Name=os.path.basename(attachment))
            part["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename={}".format(os.path.basename(attachment))
            msg.attach(part)
    
        logger.info("Sending email message from " + from_ + " to " + str(to))
        smtpObj.sendmail(from_, to, msg.as_string())
        logger.info("Logging off of " + smtp_server)
        smtpObj.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out on my own.
The following code should go in the send_mail method:

```
html = " "
if html_text is not None:
    if(isinstance(html_text, list)):
        for text in html_text or []:
            html += text
    else:
        html = html_text
    part2 = MIMEText(html, "html")
    msg.attach(part2)
```

The send_report code should be updated as follows:

```
def send_report(styles, report_date, table_title):
      send_mail(
          username = "test@test.com",
          password = 'abcde',
          from_='test@test.com',
          to = 'test@test.com',
          subject = "Test",
          html_text = styles,        
       )
```

The styles parameter should be a list of rendered Style objects but can also be a single rendered Style object